# JNI native methods not appearing in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, ini, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am studying some code involving JNI. As part of this I can creating Javdoc libraries.  See CoreMidiClient.createClient and  CoreMidiClient.disposeClient in http://bradleyross.github.io/CoreMidi4J/apidocs for the Javadoc.  The actual Git repository is http://www.github.com/BradleyRoss/CoreMidi4J.  The methods are in the Java source files but don't appear in the Javadocs.  Is there some option that I am missing or something that I am interpreting wrong.  I am using maven-javadoc-plugin to create the Javadoc files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I needed to have private in the configuration section of the maven-javadoc-plugin specifications.  This line had been lost in some cut-and-paste activity.